# Moving blip in console

Tags: c#, windows, console, slide

I want to know this thing. How to move one symbol from one side to other in Console.
I have function walk() for moving blip on console. It uses basic system of conditions and adding speed values to positions. But this is the problem:
When I want to move from 0, 0 to 60, 80, it behave like this.
It will normally move in diagonal way it it reaches the smallest position (60). Then it will just slide in Y coords to 80.
So:
Till 60; 60 position it slide in diagonal way.
When it reaches 60, it will stay at x60 and slide to y80.
But thats logical.
I want to find a way to slide between start and destination, without hanging a coords.
Uf, my english. Here is the video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89067882/problem.avi
Video explains everything.

Comment: Nevermind. It still needs a tweak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates how to make the blip move with a pre-defined speed and update interval.  Run it and see what happens...

*I added a **reference** to System.Drawing so I could use the `Point` structure.

Like @Arsalan00, we first compute the change in X and Y needed to get from A to B.  Then, given the pre-defined speed, we compute how much time is required to travel the distance between A and B.  Next we use a loop and the `Stopwatch` class to determine how much time has elapsed since we started moving the blip, pausing with `Sleep()` for the pre-defined update interval time.  With the elapsed time from the Stopwatch we can compute the "percentage of time" elapsed with respect to the total required travel time.  With the time percentage we can compute how far along the computed change in X and Y we should be at and add that to the starting point:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        public const double MillisecondsBetweenMoves = (double)100;
        public const double DistancePerSecond = (double)10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point ptStart = new Point(0, 0);
            Point ptStop = new Point(70, 15);

            int deltaX = ptStop.X - ptStart.X;
            int deltaY = ptStop.Y - ptStart.Y;
            double DistanceToTravel = Math.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));

            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStart.X, ptStart.Y);
            Console.Write("a");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStop.X, ptStop.Y);
            Console.Write("b");

            double TimeRequiredInMilliseconds = DistanceToTravel / DistancePerSecond * (double)1000;
            Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
            SW.Start();
            while (SW.ElapsedMilliseconds < TimeRequiredInMilliseconds)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)MillisecondsBetweenMoves);
                Point position = new Point(
                    ptStart.X + (int)((double)SW.ElapsedMilliseconds / TimeRequiredInMilliseconds * (double)deltaX),
                    ptStart.Y + (int)((double)SW.ElapsedMilliseconds / TimeRequiredInMilliseconds * (double)deltaY)
                    );
                Console.Clear();

                Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStart.X, ptStart.Y);
                Console.Write("a");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStop.X, ptStop.Y);
                Console.Write("b");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(position.X, position.Y);
                Console.Write("X");
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStart.X, ptStart.Y);
            Console.Write("a");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStop.X, ptStop.Y);
            Console.Write("b");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ptStop.X, ptStop.Y);
            Console.Write("X");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the horizontal distance and the vertical distance. Make a ratio out of them i.e vertical/horizontal.
Use that ratio to decide the chances of you moving in some direction.

For example, if the horizontal distance is 40 and the vertical distance is 20, the ratio comes out to be 0.5. That means you need to take 0.5 vertical moves for every 1 horizontal move, or 1 vertical move per 2 horizontal moves. Do this until you reach very close to the destination. After that use your regular walk() function to walk the next 2,3 blocks.